# Convert Rows to Columns SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just want to transpose following table

RegionID  Region     RedionCode     RegionSupervisor

```
1     Eastern    E01         Mark
2     Western    W01         Jim
3     Northern    N01        Paul
4     Southern    S01        David
```

to

Eastern         Western           Northern               Southern

```
1          2         3            4
E01        W01       N01          S01
Mark       Jim       Paul         David
```

I use SQL 2008. Any help would be really appreciated

cheers!

Comment: try PIVOT to convert rows to columns

Comment: Does this table have more than four rows? If the fifth row was 1, Eastern, E02, John, what would the expected outcome be?

Comment: Number of rows could be vary. So it needs to be something dynamic.

Comment: and 5th row could be something like 
5     South East    SE1        John

and should come to bottom table as 

SouthEast (Column)
   5    (row1)
  SE1   (row2)
  John  (row3)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) tsql commands.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample as samples I have checked so far do not give the out put I need. Even with PIVOT.

Comment: Visit the link there is well sample

Comment: I don't believe you can use PIVOT successfully unless you know in advance the full set of the columns in the resulting table. Is there only N,S,W,E,NE,NW,SW,SE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT, but you will also need to incorporate dynamic SQL, as PIVOT by itself will only support situations where you know in advance the full set of columns in the resultant table. [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, finally I found a way of doing it but possibly not the more effective way. I could not find a solution with PIVOT yet

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ColumnList varchar(200)
    DECLARE @ColumnInList varchar(200)
    DECLARE @TableName varchar(20)
    DECLARE @TableScript varchar(2000)                         

    SET @ColumnList = ''
    SET @ColumnInList = ''
    SELECT @ColumnInList += RTRIM(RegionDescription) + ',', @ColumnList += '[' + RTRIM(RegionDescription) + '] varchar(50) , '
    FROM RegionSup 

    SET @ColumnList = LEFT(@ColumnList, LEN(@ColumnList) - 1)
    SET @ColumnInList = LEFT(@ColumnInList, LEN(@ColumnInList) - 1)

    SELECT @TableName = 'TEMP' + CONVERT(char(12),GETDATE(),14);
    SELECT @TableName = REPLACE(@TableName,':','')
    SET @TableScript = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + ' (' +
                    @ColumnList + ')'

    EXECUTE (@TableScript)


    --Column Values
    DECLARE @RegionID varchar(30)
    DECLARE @RegionSupervisor varchar(50)
    DECLARE @RegionCode varchar(50)
    --End Column Values

    SET @RegionID = ''
    SET @RegionSupervisor = ''
    SET @RegionCode = ''

    SELECT @RegionID += '''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),RegionID) + ''',',
           @RegionSupervisor += '''' + RegionSupervisor + ''',',
           @RegionCode +=  '''' + RegionCode + ''','
    FROM RegionSup

    SET @RegionID = LEFT(@RegionID,LEN(@RegionID) - 1)
    SET @RegionSupervisor = LEFT(@RegionSupervisor,LEN(@RegionSupervisor) - 1)
    SET @RegionCode = LEFT(@RegionCode,LEN(@RegionCode) - 1)

    DECLARE @InsertStatement nvarchar(max)
    SET @InsertStatement = ''

    SET @InsertStatement = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + '(' +  @ColumnInList + ') VALUES ' +
                            '(' + @RegionID + '),' +
                            '(' + @RegionSupervisor + '),' +
                            '(' + @RegionCode + ')' 

    EXECUTE(@InsertStatement)                       

    EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName)
    EXECUTE('DROP TABLE ' + @TableName)
END
```

Comment: -1 the correct way to accomplish this is using `PIVOT` as @womp suggested.

Comment: Can u show me or point me to a link which gives u the same out put for the same input. I have been fiddling through lot PIVOT samples but could not find something similar

Comment: @Matthew only PIVOT doesnt work dynamically without dynamic SQL. He needs an example.

Comment: There are examples on the MSDN link provided by @womp.

Comment: they are very basic ones and I think my source table columns are in different form compare to those. and those samples do not give anything about dynamic columns as well